# Why do we define characteristic equation only for square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why do we define [characteristic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_equation) only for square matrix? I note that for otherwise in such a equation we can't put the given matrix in place of $x$ in terms like $x^2,x^3,...$ etc. Is it a reasonable answer?

Comment: The power of a matrix is only defined for square matrices.

Comment: If $A$ is not a square matrix $A^2$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn't that what I already said?

Comment: Since characteristic equations are associated to eigenvalue problems, one could first rather ask how to define the concept of eigen-stuff for rectangular matrices.

Comment: If it's that what you meant, yes. I wasn't sure what "we can't put the given matrix in place of $x$ in terms like $x^2,x^3,...$ etc" means.

Comment: Also, speaking only in terms of the polynomial in a single variable (i.e., $\det(A-\lambda\cdot I) = 0$) the determinant is only defined for square matrices.